# Spec Failure/Error: current_path.should ==tasks_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on this tutorial(time is 33:55): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/

While what is shown at localhost:3000 is correct and functions properly, I'm still getting an rspec error.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Ruby 1.9.2p290
Rails 3.2.3
RSpec 2.11.0

Error:
Running: spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb spec/controllers/tasks_controller_spec.rb
..F.

Failures:

```
   1) Tasks PUT/tasks edits a task
       Failure/Error: current_path.should == tasks_path
        expected: "/tasks"
           got: "/tasks/1/edit" (using ==)
       # ./spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
       '
```

tasks_controller.rb:

```
     class TasksController < ApplicationController
        def index
         @task = Task.new
         @tasks = Task.all
        end

        def create
          Task.create params[:task]
          redirect_to :back
        end

        def edit
          @task = Task.find params[:id]
        end

        def update
          task = Task.find params[:id]
            if task.update_attributes params[:task]
              redirect_to tasks_path
            else
              redirect_to :back
            end
        end

       end
```

tasks_spec.rb:

require 'spec_helper'

```
 describe "Tasks" do
    before do
    @task = Task.create :task => 'go to bed'
end

describe "GET /tasks" do
    it "display some tasks" do

       visit tasks_path
       page.should have_content 'go to bed'
    end

    it "creates a new task" do
       visit tasks_path
       fill_in 'Task', :with => 'go to work'
       click_button 'Create Task'

       current_path.should == tasks_path
       page.should have_content 'go to work'

       #save_and_open_page
    end
end  

describe "PUT/tasks" do
    it "edits a task" do
        visit tasks_path
        click_link 'Edit'

        current_path = edit_task_path(@task)

        #page.should have_content 'go to bed'
        find_field('Task').value.should == 'go to bed'

        fill_in 'Task', :with => 'updated task'
        click_button 'Update Task'

        current_path.should == tasks_path

        page.should have_content 'updated task'
    end
```

end
     end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that by doing this assignment...

> current_path = edit_task_path(@task)

...you created a new variable called 'current_path' which overwrote capybara's.

The moral of the story is don't assign to 'current_path'

Comment: thanks!  I commented out that line in the "edits a tasks" block and it fixed the test failure I was getting.  Much appreciated!